# How to solve continuous alert box over in java script?

Tags: javascript

I had created an registration form and made an validation using javascript..while on validation i had got an error over an continuous alert on my browser...here after entered my proper mobile number it alerts me thus it was valid...then it continuously shows the alert  function that "email was not valid"....

Here Is my Code >>

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Login-Form</title>
<style>
h3{
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: Cyan;
 color: Red;
 size: 20px;
}
.log-in{
 padding: 50px;
 background-image: url("login.png");
 align: left;
 color: Cyan;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color:black;
 
}
.Register{
 padding: 50px;
 background-image: url("reg.png");
 align: Right;
 color: Yellow;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color:black;
 
}
</style>
<body>
<div>
<marquee><center><h3>Welcome To LIFOA Mobile-APP</h3></center></marquee>
<form class="log-in" method="post">
 <table>
 <b>
 <tr>
  <td><h1>LOGIN PAGE</h1><br><br><br></td>
  <td>USER NAME</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="text1" name="un" onBlur="checkuser()"/></td><br /><br><br>
  <td><span id="user_status" style="color:Red ;font-weight:400"> </span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>PASSWORD</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td><input type="password" name="pw"  placeholder="Password" id="text2"/></td><br /><br><br>
  <td><span id="user_status" style="color:Red ;font-weight:400"onBlur="checkpass()"> </td></span>
  <td><span id="user_status" style="color:Red ;font-weight:400"> </span></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="javascript:validate()" /></b></center>
 </form>
</div>
<div>
<form action="..." class="Register" method="get" >
 <b>
  <center><h2>Register</h1><br><br><br>
  NAME: <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" id="text" /> <br /><br><br>
  <label>Enter phone number (e.g. (123) 456-7890): 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Mob Number" id="text4" name="Mobile" onBlur="checkPhoneNo(this.value);"  />
  </label> <br /><br><br>
  <label>Enter mail ID: 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" id="text5" name="mail" onBlur="ValidateEmail(this.value);"  />
  </label><br /><br><br>
  Gender : 
 <br>
 <input type="radio" value="male">Male
          <br>
          <input type="radio" value="female">FeMale
    <br>
          <input type="radio" value="other">Other
 <br>
 <br>
  Password: <input type="password" placeholder="Enter  Password" id="text2" /><br /><BR><BR>
  Confirm Password: <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm the password" id="text3" /><br /><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Register" /></b></center>
</form> 
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- Mobile number coding using Regular expression -!>
function checkPhoneNo(phoneNo) {
alert(phoneNo);
  var phoneRE = /^\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d$/;
  if (phoneNo.match(phoneRE)) {
 alert("Number valid");
    return true;
  } 
  else {
 alert("The phone number is not valid");
    return false;
  }
}

function ValidateEmail(mail) 
{
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(mail))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
 {
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
    return false;
 }
}

  
function checkuser()<!--Username box indication in different colour when it leaves empty -!>
{
 un=document.getElementById("text1").style.border="1px solid #ff0000";
 if(un=="");
  document.getElementById('user_status').innerHTML="Please Enter the userName";
}
function checkpass()
{
 un=document.getElementById("text2").style.border="1px solid #ff0000";
 if(un=="");
  document.getElementById('passw_status').innerHTML="Please Enter the Password";
 alert("Enter password");
}
function validate()
{
  if(   document.getElementById("text1").value == "Suganth"
       && document.getElementById("text2").value == "6213" )
    {
        alert( "validation succeeded" );
        location.href="second.html";
    }
else
{
        alert( "Invalid credentials" );
        location.href="first.html";
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not return from the JS validation function it will stop the default blur action.

```
function checkPhoneNo(phoneNo) {
    var phoneRE = /^\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d$/;
    if (phoneNo.match(phoneRE)) {
        alert("Number valid");
        //return true;
    } else {
        alert("The phone number is not valid");
        //return false;
    }
}
```

My suggestion to setup validation in JS is you should validation while form submission so you can show the consolidated error.

And do not user browser alert it look odd as user experience, For your learning it is okay.